# Cannot register assembly. Specific module could not be found

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop, add-in

I'm trying to compile an excel addin solution that was developed in C#. Everything goes well when compiling but at the end, I receive the following message:

Error   1   Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\bandrade\HTBase\Programs\Palo\HTOSE\HTOSE\2.5\XlAddin\bin\Debug\Jedox.Palo.XlAddin.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  3341

Does anyone have any ideas?

One test I did is, if I uncheck the "Register for COM interop" it compiles fine and this error goes away but then the .dll is not recognized by Excel and I receive the following error message:

".dll is not a valid Excel addin"

How can I compile it successfully without unchecking the "Register for COM interop"?

This is the routine that makes the error prompt:

```
Registers the main assembly for COM interop.
============================================================
-->
<PropertyGroup>
    <UnmanagedRegistrationDependsOn></UnmanagedRegistrationDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target
    Name="UnmanagedRegistration"
    Condition="'$(RegisterForComInterop)'=='true' and '$(OutputType)'=='library'"
    DependsOnTargets="$(UnmanagedRegistrationDependsOn)"
    >

    <RegisterAssembly
        Assemblies="@(_OutputPathItem->'%(FullPath)$(TargetFileName)')"
        TypeLibFiles="@(_OutputPathItem->'%(FullPath)$(TargetName).tlb')"
        AssemblyListFile="@(_UnmanagedRegistrationCache)"
        CreateCodeBase="true"
        Condition="!Exists('@(_UnmanagedRegistrationCache)')"/>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FileWrites Include="@(_OutputPathItem->'%(FullPath)$(TargetName).tlb')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can't find a file.  Not sure how you expect us to find it for you.  Contact Jedox for support.

Comment: thanks for your very kind response, very polite!! the file Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll is in the references for the solution but somehow it stills saying that it can't find

Comment: its probably running a regasm command. try to find out what that command is. also check that you don't have any dependencies that need to have copy local set to true

Comment: Is there any good and practical way to check if there are dependencies?